# Changing the time it takes for the mousehover event to fire

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, mousehover

I'm making a winforms C# project with .NET 4.

I want to display a tooltip when the mouse hovers over a button or a textbox or whatever. Right now it displays almost as soon as the mouse stops moving. I don't like this. I want it to have more of a delay.

Is there any way I can set a mousehover event delay time that is the same for all installed users?

I suppose I could start a timer, and then cancel the timer when the mouse moves again but there's got to be a better way by golly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I think it will really help You

```
 ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
 t.InitialDelay = 500;
 t.SetToolTip(button1, "Hello");
```

Comment: I wasn't using set tool tip, i was using tooltip.show and a manual mousehover. this is why initial delay wasn't working for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the InitialDelay property of the Tooltip to insert a delay. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.initialdelay.aspx

Comment: It's not working, but its probably because I'm manually making tooltips and showing them on the mousehover event instead of using the built in tooltip mousehover stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You could experiment with `SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime` property. I suppose it's system-wide

Comment: How to experiment? It is read only.